# What does assigning a null value to a variable in a function parameter mean?

Tags: php, function

I've been following some OOP in PHP tutorials on TheNewBoston. The host passed a string as an actual parameter in one of the class's function and he assigned null value to a variable as formal parameter. I didn't get what and why did he do that.

Here's the code:

Config.php

```
class Config
{
    public static function get($path=null)
    {
        if($path)
        {
            $path = explode('/', $path);
            print_r($path);         
        }
    }
}
```

Index.php

```
Config::get('mysql/host');
```

The code outputs Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => host ).

But what does assigning null to $path means? and why is null value not being assigned to $path?

Comment: It sets a default value, so you can call the method without passing in that parameter

Comment: In the function definition, that's not a straight assignment.... it's the assignment of a default value _if no actual value is passed when the function is called_ [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Comment: And it's not specifically OOP either, applies to PHP in general